# Entity Framework: Best way to delete an entity when another entity gets deleted?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have orders and orders have lines. When one deletes the last order line the order should be deleted as well. I'm struggling to find the best place for this.

The developer would just call context.Remove(orderLine) to remove the line. So the logic to then delete the order if this was the last line should be in the remove call.

The current idea would be to create a OrderLineDbSet which inherits from the DbSet and overwrite the Remove call there. But the issue is, that I don't have access to the DataContext because dependency injection does not work here...

Id did a bit of digging into https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbSet.cs but I couldn't figure it out.

The last code i tried was kind of this:

```
public class OrderLineDbSet : DbSet<OrderLine>
{
    CourseContext context { get; set; }

    public OrderLineDbSet(CourseContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override OrderLine Add(OrderLine entity)
    {
        return base.Add(entity);
    }

    public override OrderLine Remove(OrderLine entity)
    {
        Order order = entity.Order;

        var line = base.Remove(entity);

        if (!order.OrderLines.Any())
        {
            context.Orders.Remove(order);
        }

        return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an approach to get the context out of the entity (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx) but there might be a better way?

Comment: Can't you write a partial class `OrderLine` and create a method for doing what you need?

Comment: Don't overload `DbSet` like that. What if you delete the last line and subsequently add a new one in one transaction? It's an almost universal truth that children shouldn't rule their parents.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to push business logic into data access layer. Usually, you have a class, which implements some business logic, e.g.:

```
public class OrdersService
{
    public void RemoveOrderLine(OrderLine orderLine)
    {
        // get db context (or some repository)
        var context = GetDbContext();
        // attach or load entities, etc.

        // this is _business logic_;
        // it is not natural for relational database;
        // it is not related to db context or repositiory
        context.OrderLines.Remove(orderLine);
        if (!order.OrderLines.Any())
        {
            context.Orders.Remove(order);
        }        
    }
}
```

In other words. Imagine, that after last line was removed, user must receive SMS, that order was removed too. Here's an action, that is totally unrelated to database. Do you want to put SMS sending in `DbSet`?

Comment: Indeed I do use this approach currently. But I wanted to get aways from services because it is more convenient to call context.Remove instead of using the service (or at least there are both options which feels bad). But like Gert posted in the other comment it is not a good idea to delete the order from the line as I do not know if the caller will add another line later on. So the requirement is not correct at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should be set up with mapping and let entity framework remove the whole object graph.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                    .HasMany(a => a.Lines)
                    .WithRequired(b => b.Orders)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cascade deletion works from principal entity to dependent. When removing an order, remove all its lines. OP wants to remove order (principal entity) when last line (dependent entity) removed. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Then this approach could still be used. Check that the last line is attempting to be removed and just remove the order which will takes the line with it.

Comment: Yes, but that changes the process considerably. The cascaded delete would merely facilitate it, but not take care of it. So this can't be an answer.